# need help on Regular expression

Tags: perl

We have a file with below syntax:

```
I/P : abc_com.an.gx3d_02-20-2014_05-26-38.txt
O/P : abc_com.an.gx3d
```

I am trying to remove the part which starts with a timestamp. I tried with the below code but it's not working:

```
(my $test = $file) =~ s/^\d{2}\.*//;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ^ anchor is forcing your regex to only match at the beginning of the string.  You probably want something closer to the following:

```
(my $test = $file) =~ s/_\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}_.*//;
```